# How do i edit the data in the dataTable before it is being displayed into the dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

im doing a C# Windows Form Application. I would like you to know a few things up first. I'm using a local access database. I have been trying to get the Month to be converted to a MonthName from the AccessDB. Well i have tried using the DATENAME Function but it couldn't work. So i thought if i could edit the dataTable before it is being put into the datGridView for Display. PLease help me out. Please take a look at the coding.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // display amount havent cleared the month yet
    {
        sum.Visible = true;
        // 1
        // Open connection\
        string companyName = comboBox1.Text;
        string connectionString = null;
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DPE2.mdb;";
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        {
            conn.Open();
            // 
            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (OleDbDataAdapter a = new OleDbDataAdapter(
                "SELECT MONTH(Date) AS [Month], SUM(Amount) AS [Amount] FROM Statements Where Customer_name ='" + companyName + "' group By MONTH(Date)", conn))
            {
                // 3
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);
                // 4
                // Render data onto the screen
                dataGridView3.DataSource = t; 
            }

            int z = 0;
            while (z < dataGridView3.Rows.Count)
            {
                string data = dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].ToString();

                switch (data)
                {
                    case "1":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Equals("Jan");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "Feb";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "Mar";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "April";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "May";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "June";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "July";
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "August";
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "September";
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "October";
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "Novemeber";
                        break;
                    case "12":
                        dataGridView3.Rows[z].Cells[0].Value = "December";
                        break;
                }
                z++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing you select query like this.

SELECT convert(char(3), Date, 0) AS [Month], SUM(Amount) AS [Amount] FROM Statements Where Customer_name ='" + companyName + "' group By MONTH(Date)"

This will give you the month directly in 3 letters so need to implement extra logic to handle the datagridView cell text for setting month in 3 letters.

Or If you don't want to change you query then implement the logic that will add one extra column like MonthText for 3 Letter Month in dataTable only. then bind this new table with your DataGridView.

Comment: It shows me the Undefined function 'convert' in expression. Is it because Access Database have their own sets of SQL Statements and expression to follow. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I think that leave me with the 2nd Option which is to add one extra column